# 'Missing app link URL' on Facebook app invite

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to setup Facebook app invites, but I keep getting :'The app link used in this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL'

I am using my website as the URL, which contains these meta tags:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="(myapplink)" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="(myappid)" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="(myappname)" />
<meta property="og:title" content="(myappname)" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a [app link from there](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host) if you haven't already. The steps are simple, you'll get a link like `https://fb.me/***********`.

Then you just have to use this link as your app link, like that :

```
    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/***********"];
    //optionally set previewImageURL
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://anImageHost.com/img.png"];
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the invite dialog was actually checking if  the custom URL scheme used in the `content.appLinkURL` property was working or not. If this hasn't been configured, the app invite will fail with the error message you've described.

Real simple instructions for configuring and testing the URL scheme are here:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html